# Not able to send mail in Golang

Tags: email, go, gmail

I am trying to send mail on my local system using `gmail` package of `golang`. For which I tried the following:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "github.com/SlyMarbo/gmail"
)

func main() {
    email := gmail.Compose("Email subject", "Email body")
    email.From = "account@gmail.com"
    email.Password = "password"

    // Defaults to "text/plain; charset=utf-8" if unset.
    email.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8"

    // Normally you'll only need one of these, but I thought I'd show both.
    email.AddRecipient("recepient@domain.com")

    err := email.Send()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        // handle error.
    }
}
```

I am neither getting any error nor mail. Not sure if it is not sent due to local server. Can anyone please guide me what am I missing? I took reference from [this](https://github.com/SlyMarbo/gmail) page.

Comment: do you know your `smpt` configuration at your local server? such as port? etc. My suggestion is read the library code try setup or change the `net/smpt` to your local config

Comment: what do you mean by local config of smtp?

Comment: Check the Sent folder for the account you're sending from to see if it has gone out. Also try checking the Spam folder.